# i got this error in objective c - chromecast app

Tags: objective-c, casting, stream, chromecast

i follow after this guide here "https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/ios_sender"

i'll create an app there will stream an video too chromecast.

but i got this error here:
[image]

how can i strream a chromecast with objective c - IOS app

Comment: Do you have that classes in the headers of `GoogleCast.framework`? From what I remember, there are 2/3 different pods available (check that you get the good one), and that scanner is in fact deprecated, so if you used the new pod, you should use GCKDiscoverySomething instead.

Comment: Yes, i have the GoogleCast.framwork. as you can see in the photo left side.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't tell me which version you use, and I don't want to download myself the pod to check that. At some point you have to do some work/debugging by yourself.

Comment: my pod --version is: 1.5.0, Inside Podfile: pod 'google-cast-sdk'..

Comment: well all error related to you viewcontroller.h file if you kindly share sample project or the .h screenshot as well thank you

Comment: Use `GCKDiscoveryManager` instead. `GCKDeviceScanner` was at least in 3 version (http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/google-cast-sdk/3.4.0/Classes/GCKDeviceScanner.html) but was replaced by `GCKDiscoveryManager`. See there: https://developers.google.com/cast/v3/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_device_scanner the list of objects

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is deprecated.

By default, using `pod 'google-cast-sdk'`, you should get last version of the pod.

Issue, `GCKDeviceScanner` which is a 2.0 API has been deprecated in 3.0 and removed in 4.0.

See [release note](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes):

> November 14, 2017
>
> iOS Sender v4.0
>
> • Variable playback rate - Added UI elements to display and change the
>   playback rate for the current media item. Made changes to
>   `GCKRemoteMediaClient`, `GCKUIMediaController`, and
>   `GCKUIPlaybackRateController`. For details, see variable playback rate.
>   • **Removed all deprecated classes from 2.x versions - The major ones are
>   GCKDeviceManager, GCKDeviceScanner, GCKMediaControlChannel, and all
>   the Game Manager APIs.** GCKAnalyticsLoggingEnabled has also been
>   removed. 
> • Bug fix - Fixed an issue where some memory would leak when a
>   Cast session ended.

From the [documentation of `GCKDeviceScanner](https://developers.google.com/cast/v3/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_device_scanner):

> Deprecated: Use GCKDiscoveryManager to discover Cast receivers.

If you check yours headers files as I asked, you won't find it:
[image]

So either check an updated tutorial or downgrade the version of the pod (but not recommended, use last version).